# Automatic cycle detection of signals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, cycle

I am working on a power consumption signal in MATLAB. What I would like to do is to measure cycle times, e.g idle time and working time. Moreover, I extract power consumption signatures. The code is giving me also the number of signatures (`numberofoccurrences`).

I use the cross correlation method (`xcorr`) and the `findpeaks` function to autocorrelate the signal. The code:

```
S=S-mean(S);%%%%//Signal that I am working with. It's a 200X1 double
%%%%%%%%
IdleLevel = min(S)*1.4;%this will help find peaks above a minimum threshold
invS=-S;% minimum point becomes max
%%%%%%%%


%//find peaks in the inverse signal. hard coded though!
[pks, locs]=findpeaks(invS,'MinPeakHeight',IdleLevel,'MinPeakDistance',40);
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%//signature extraction
for n = 1:length(locs)-1;
    sig{n} = S(locs(n):locs(n+1));
end;
%%%%%

%%%%%%%%//correlation between signal and signature 1
[c,lags] = xcorr(S,sig{1});
%%%%%%%%% 

%%%//normalisation
c = (1/max(c)).*c; 
%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%
[peaksx, locsx] = findpeaks(c, 'MinPeakHeight',0.8,'MinPeakDistance',40);
%%%% 
%%%% 
numberofoccurrences = length(locsx)
Signatures = sig;
```

the signal that I am working with looks like this:

[image]

An example of a signature that I extract is this:

[image]

And from what is shown in picture 2 there are two areas of interest. The idle one and the working one.

I need to find a way to calculate the working time and the idle time. I am doing this and what I take is (I think) the `total_time`.

```
for k=1:numberofoccurrences
    total_time(k)=length(sig{k});
end
```

The `minpeakdistance` is hard coded. If there is a technique that does not use a predefined value it would be perfect.